# jRuby / Rails is there an equivalent function to PHP substr() to remove the last character from a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, jruby

What I have is a dynamically created list thats built off a "each" loop. Where every variable it tacks on it also adds "," to that string, basically making a CSV style list. What I want to do is remove the last character. Because at the end of the run through the loop there is the extra "," at the end.

I am trying to find the equivalent to this from PHP

```
echo substr($str,0,($len-1));
```

based on the Rails For PHP site it says do something like

```
puts @avaliable_list.slice(0, 1)
```

and

```
puts @avaliable_list[0, 1]
```

which either rails version leaves me with only the very first character of the string, does not remove the last piece like I want it to. The Rails for PHP site would have me believe that 0 represents the end of the string, and the 1 would be the total char's I want to remove from said string. Instead it does the opposite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `join` the array instead of using `each`.

```
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :003 > [1,2,3,4].join(',')
=> "1,2,3,4"
```

Answer (score 2):

[String#[]](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D)

```
irb(main):006:0> 'abc'[0..-2]
=> "ab"
```

Comment: Honestly, the author is first looping on an array, adding `,`, appending to a string and then want to remove the last character. If you join an array using `join` itself, it takes care of not putting the last `,`, and concatenates everything into a string, which is what the author really wants.

Comment: Well, we can't know why he's doing that in a loop, there are plenty reasons why one might do that instead of join, maybe his data is not in an array in the first place, maybe he scans a string in the loop etc. Nevertheless I think you are right so I'll +1 you.

Comment: One obvious reason for building the string via loop is to conditionally quote values (i.e. quote strings but not ints).  Or there might be other logic involved.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `chomp`.

[Doc here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-chomp).

Re-reading, your question, you might consider `truncate`.

[Doc here.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#truncate)